# How to get a comparable date parsing "13:00"?

Tags: java, datetime

I was trying with:

```
new Date("13:00")
```

All I care about is the time of day and that when compared new Date("12:00") is less than new Date("13:00"). Is there no library for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create two Dates and set only the hours and minutes (e.g. by parsing with a time format pattern or by setting fields in a Calendar) you can compare them.

java.util.Date provides [before](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before%28java.util.Date%29) and [after](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#after%28java.util.Date%29) methods for date comparison. It also implements Comparable#[compareTo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29), so you can test for before/equals/after in one invocation.

```
    // get dates using format/parse
    DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date1 = format.parse("13:00");
    Date date2 = format.parse("13:00");

    // use Date comparison methods
    boolean before = date1.before(date2);
    System.err.println(before);

    // use compareTo
    int compare = date1.compareTo(date2);
    System.err.println(compare);

    // get dates using Calendar
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 12);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    date1 = calendar.getTime();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 13);
    date2 = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

If the times are in "HH:mm" format you can just compare the strings.

```
String time1 = "12:00";
String time2 = "13:00";
int compared = time1.compareTo(time2); // compared == -1
```

Comment: It one of the reasons I use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` or variations in file names because they will be sorted by date when sorted by name.

Answer (score 1):

[JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) is very popular in Java. Take a look at [LocalTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html).